# Rails server gets response, but localhost page hangs randomly until system reboot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, webpacker

I'm working on a project with a Rails 6.0 backend using webpacker with a React frontend. While working on the frontend with the rails server, my app will sometimes break on Google Chrome, endlessly loading but never even showing the new page title on the tab.

The rails server is receiving the request. It will hit debuggers in the backend and it returns with a 200 status code, but Chrome refuses to load the page while giving no errors or messages indicating what is wrong. This persists even after I restart the rails server, if I restart it on a different port, and if I restart the webpack dev server. I've tried clearing my cache and disabling the cache with devtools, but the only thing that fixes it is rebooting my entire system.

It seems to happen randomly, though I think it may be happening if I refresh the page out of the chrome debugger. I am using ajax for calls to my backend API, not sure if that's possibly a factor.

I've never had this problem before and I'm unsure what it even possibly could be. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here?